# Some difference between code in notepad and code in VS

Tags: c

So I made up some code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SMALLSTRLEN 3
#define BIGSTRLEN 4
#define SMALLASCIIA 97
#define BIGASCIIA 65
#define BIGASCIIZ 90
#define SMALLASCIIZ 122
int main(void)
{

    int i = 0,j=0,q=0;
    char str[] = "SHaddOW";
    char smallStr[SMALLSTRLEN];
    char bigStr[BIGSTRLEN];
    printf("%s", str);
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= SMALLASCIIA) && (str[i] <= SMALLASCIIZ))
        {
            smallStr[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if ((str[i] >= BIGASCIIA) && (str[i] <= BIGASCIIZ))
        {
            bigStr[q] = str[i];
            q++;
        }
    }
    bigStr[q] = "\0";
    puts(smallStr);
    puts(bigStr);
    printf("\n\n\n%s", bigStr);
    //getchar();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The `bigStr` needs to have all the upper-case letters, and the `smallStr` all the lower-case letters from the original `str`. The output in the notepad++ with gcc compiler is: `bigStr= SHOWadd , smallStr = add`

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: The compiler should be giving you a warning that explains one part of the problem. If you don't fix the compiler warnings, then you shouldn't expect your code to work.  The other problems: `BIGSTRLEN` and `SMALLSTRLEN` aren't big enough, and `smallStr` needs a NUL terminator.

Comment: why `#define BIGASCIIA 65`? A is not always 65. Use `'A'` instead, more correct and easier to read

Answer (score 1):

This code has buffer overruns and unterminated strings. That is the reason you are getting different results with two compilers: you are invoking undefined behavior.

Your test string has seven characters, three lowercase and four uppercase.

You are appending those characters to the `smallStr` and `bigStr` arrays, but those arrays only have room for the actual characters you're appending, without allowing for a null terminator.

When you set `bigStr[q] = "\0";`, you have already filled the `bigStr` array with four characters. The null terminator is being written in an undefined place after the end of the array.

The `smallStr` array does not receive a null terminator at all. If it did, it would also be past the end of the array in the same way as `bigStr`.

The lengths of `smallStr` and `bigStr` are hard coded. What happens if you use a different test string?

What is your goal in writing this code? Perhaps you should consider writing it in C++ using `std::string` to avoid these problems.

If you do want to write it in C with no string library, consider making two passes over the source string. The first pass would merely *count* the number of lowercase and uppercase characters. Then, you can allocate two arrays of the correct size (don't forget the null terminator). Then the second pass can fill the two arrays and append the null terminator to each.